# Bootstrap Special Character Showing Randomly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Beginner here, sorry if this is a simple thing.

I am using someone's work to make checkbox buttons, as found here:

http://jsfiddle.net/DcYhf/36/

source:

(Sorry, can only post one link at a time. But please Google bootsnipp checkbox buttons)

This uses Bootstrap 3.1.1 as far as I know.

When I copy the fiddle code to a plain html file and embed the javascript, I get a weird looking 'A' symbol in front of the text. If I delete the word 'Success', then only the 'A' symbol appears.

Here is an example of what my problem is:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/81zV3.png

I re-copied the code. I made sure I have bootstrap v 3.1.1 and everything is correctly loading. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>

  <title>Example of Twitter Bootstrap</title>
   <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(function () {
    $('.button-checkbox').each(function () {

        // Settings
        var $widget = $(this),
            $button = $widget.find('button'),
            $checkbox = $widget.find('input:checkbox'),
            color = $button.data('color'),
            settings = {
                on: {
                    icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-check'
                },
                off: {
                    icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked'
                }
            };

        // Event Handlers
        $button.on('click', function () {
            $checkbox.prop('checked', !$checkbox.is(':checked'));
            $checkbox.triggerHandler('change');
            updateDisplay();
        });
        $checkbox.on('change', function () {
            updateDisplay();
        });

        // Actions
        function updateDisplay() {
            var isChecked = $checkbox.is(':checked');

            // Set the button's state
            $button.data('state', (isChecked) ? "on" : "off");

            // Set the button's icon
            $button.find('.state-icon')
                .removeClass()
                .addClass('state-icon ' + settings[$button.data('state')].icon);

            // Update the button's color
            if (isChecked) {
                $button
                    .removeClass('btn-default')
                    .addClass('btn-' + color + ' active');
            }
            else {
                $button
                    .removeClass('btn-' + color + ' active')
                    .addClass('btn-default');
            }
        }

        // Initialization
        function init() {

            updateDisplay();

            // Inject the icon if applicable
            if ($button.find('.state-icon').length === 0) {
                $button.prepend('<i class="state-icon ' + settings[$button.data('state')].icon + '"></i> ');
            }
        }
        init();
    });
});





var     new_checkbox_button = function(name,id){
            return "<li><span class='button-checkbox'><button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary active' data-color='primary'><i class='state-icon glyphicon glyphicon-check'></i>&nbsp;"+name+"</button><input type='checkbox' class='hidden' checked=''></span></li>";
        };

$("#add").click(function(){
       $("#selected_targets").append(new_checkbox_button("lallalala","1111"));
});
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<p> Existing checkboxes</p>


    <span class="button-checkbox">
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-color="success">Success</button>
        <input type="checkbox" class="hidden" checked />
    </span>

    <span class = "button-checkbox">
        <button type = "button" class = "btn" data-color = "success"> Success </button>
        <input type = "checkbox" class = "hidden" unchecked />
    </span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think this is because of your font doesnt support this. Check your font usage. Try once removing your font

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How exactly do I remove the font?

Comment: Check your css file. Do you use any `font-family` attribute? if so remove the line or comment out the line.

Comment: No CSS has been included in this. Would you know if i require to download some bootstrap-specific fonts or something?

Comment: No bootstrap CSS file is enough

Comment: check if css file path is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone on reddit figured it out for me. It is because I forgot to put the meta tags for the encoding type (UTF8):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>


     </head>
     <body>
        <div class="container"> 
        <span class="button-checkbox">
            <button type="button" class="btn" data-color="success">Success</button>
            <input type="checkbox" class="hidden" checked />
        </span>


        <script>

    $(function () {
    $('.button-checkbox').each(function () {

        // Settings
        var $widget = $(this),
            $button = $widget.find('button'),
            $checkbox = $widget.find('input:checkbox'),
            color = $button.data('color'),
            settings = {
                on: {
                    icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-check'
                },
                off: {
                    icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked'
                }
            };

        // Event Handlers
        $button.on('click', function () {
            $checkbox.prop('checked', !$checkbox.is(':checked'));
            $checkbox.triggerHandler('change');
            updateDisplay();
        });
        $checkbox.on('change', function () {
            updateDisplay();
        });

        // Actions
        function updateDisplay() {
            var isChecked = $checkbox.is(':checked');

            // Set the button's state
            $button.data('state', (isChecked) ? "on" : "off");

            // Set the button's icon
            $button.find('.state-icon')
                .removeClass()
                .addClass('state-icon ' + settings[$button.data('state')].icon);

            // Update the button's color
            if (isChecked) {
                $button
                    .removeClass('btn-default')
                    .addClass('btn-' + color + ' active');
            }
            else {
                $button
                    .removeClass('btn-' + color + ' active')
                    .addClass('btn-default');
            }
        }

        // Initialization
        function init() {

            updateDisplay();

            // Inject the icon if applicable
            if ($button.find('.state-icon').length == 0) {
                $button.prepend('<i class="state-icon ' + settings[$button.data('state')].icon + '"></i> ');
            }
        }
        init();
    });
});


     </script>

    </div>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you're trying to use the Glyphicons included in Bootstrap and the icon font can't be found.

To test if this is indeed the problem open for example Chrome's DevTools and look in the Network tab to see that a resource like `glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff` can't be found.

Another easy way to test this is to temporarily use a cdn, change `<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` into `<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />`.

By default Bootstrap looks for the fonts in `../fonts` relative to your css. As your css is `css/bootstrap.min.css` it looks for `fonts`. Create a `fonts` folder and copy the contents of Bootstraps fonts folder to it.

Comment: Thanks. I did all of your suggestions and I am getting the same problem. I'll keep looking into it and will accept your answer once I figure it out.